# Node.js: how to tell if two paths are on the same drive (cross-platform solution)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, electron, drive

In my Electron/Node.js app I need to determine whether two paths are on the same drive.

On Windows I could use `path.parse(myPath).root` to get the drive letter of each path.  But on Mac or Linux that will just return '/', according to [the Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_parse_path).

Is there a cross-platform way to know whether two paths are on the same drive? Or failing that, how do I tell on Mac?  On Linux?

Comment: What do you mean with drive in a *nix environment? Drives are Windows specific.

Comment: Yeah, not drive letters of course on non-Windows.  The issue is any given drive has only so much space, and I need to know if the two paths I'm dealing with point to the same drive.  I'm not concerned about distinguishing between virtual and physical drives, btw.

Comment: What do you mean with drives? Do you mean devices or partitions? What about different protocols like SMB, SSHFS or NFS. On Linux you can mount network folders or other remote systems into your filesystem. What if I share a local folder in the network and mount it with SMB? Are these two mount points different "drives" or the same? You have paths that don't point to any physical devise like /proc/12345 or /dev/null. /dev/null has unlimited space ;-)

Comment: What about RAID? One path can be shared over multiple physical devices. AFAIK you can do similar things with LVM. The concept of "drives" as you know and expect it on Windows doesn't exist on other systems.

Comment: My case is not that complicated.  We are talking about a very simple use case where a non-techy user has a laptop, running Windows, Mac, or Linux.  They will have one or two internal HDDs or SSDs and perhaps one or more external HDDs or SSDs connected via USB.  I need to know if two paths are on the same physical drive.  The solution does not need to take into account any of the more advanced scenarios you mention.

Comment: What if the path doesn't point to any HDD or SSD, e.g. /proc/10 or /dev/null or /sys/...?

Comment: What if the path doesn't point to any HDD or SSD, e.g. /proc/10 or /dev/null or /sys/...? AFAIK there is no API in Node.js to access partition or device information. That would mean you have to fork child processes to start system tools or write some code in C or C++. That would also mean there is no cross-platform solution. You need a specific solution for each supported platform.

Comment: The path won't be anything like that.  The user simply selects where to save a backup, using a standard dialog.  I need to compare the path they chose with another path that I create, to see if they are on the same physical hard drive (or SSD).  If separate code is necessary for each OS, that's ok - I just need to know how, for each OS, to get  a most-of-the-time accurate answer given the limitations of my use case.  If someone can defeat the logic by doing something unusual for a non-techy, I'm not concerned about that.

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, AFAIK there is no API in Node.js to find out the disk or partition by path or even access any information about disks or partitions. Remember that you can nest mount points. You can mount one partition in /data and another partition in /data/files. And there are also symbolic links. You can access /data through /home/user/m1 and /data/files through /home/user/m2. I expect this task to be non-trivial.

Comment: For Linux you can read `/proc/mounts` for a list of all mount points and devices. You can convert paths with symbolic links to actual absolute paths with [fs.realpath](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_realpath_path_options_callback). Then you should be able to find the corresponding partition for a path. `/proc/partitions` contains a list of all partitions and the number of blocks.